# Why isn't it legal to convert "pointer to pointer to non-const" to a "pointer to pointer to const"

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, const-correctness

It *is* legal to convert a pointer-to-non-const to a pointer-to-const.

Then why isn't it legal to convert a *pointer to pointer to non-const* to a *pointer to pointer to const*?

E.g., why is the following code illegal:

```
char *s1 = 0;
const char *s2 = s1; // OK...
char *a[MAX]; // aka char **
const char **ps = a; // error!
```

Comment: I suggest you define "a" as "char **", your example will be clearer without an unnecessary array.

Comment: `*a[MAX]` does not result in `char**` but actually `char** const`. Also: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17.

Comment: Yes but his question applies as well when a is char**.

Comment: you are changing the constness. These types are not the same and your compiler complains about it. With an explicit cast you tell the compiler you know what you are doing.

Comment: I do now the types are different. Pointer to constant and ordinary pointer are different as well, however you're allowed to assign pointer to constant a value of ordinary pointer. I am aware of explicit casts and avoid using those unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: below explanation is pretty good actually.

Comment: @MaxShawabkeh it decays to `char**`, there is no `const` .

Comment: Looks like a question I answered was merged w/ this one, see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29240053/1708801) which is now part of your question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From the standard:

```
const char c = 'c';
char* pc;
const char** pcc = &pc;   // not allowed
*pcc = &c;
*pc = 'C';                // would allow to modify a const object
```

Answer (score 25):

Ignoring your code and answering the principle of your question, see this entry from the comp.lang.c FAQ:
[Why can't I pass a char ** to a function which expects a const char **?](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html)

> The reason that you cannot assign a `char **` value to a `const char **` pointer is somewhat obscure. Given that the `const` qualifier exists at all, the compiler would like to help you keep your promises not to modify `const` values. That's why you can assign a `char *` to a `const char *`, but not the other way around: it's clearly safe to "add" `const`-ness to a simple pointer, but it would be dangerous to take it away. However, suppose you performed the following more complicated series of assignments:
>
> ```
> const char c = 'x';    /* 1 */
> char *p1;              /* 2 */
> const char **p2 = &p1; /* 3 */
> *p2 = &c;              /* 4 */
> *p1 = 'X';             /* 5 */
> ```
>
> In line 3, we assign a `char **` to a `const char **`. (The compiler should complain.) In line 4, we assign a `const char *` to a `const char *`; this is clearly legal. In line 5, we modify what a `char *` points to--this is supposed to be legal. However, `p1` ends up pointing to `c`, which is `const`. This came about in line 4, because `*p2` was really `p1`. This was set up in line 3, which is an assignment of a form that is disallowed, and this is exactly why line 3 is disallowed.

And as your question is tagged C++ and not C, it even explains what `const` qualifiers to use instead:

> (C++ has more complicated rules for assigning const-qualified pointers which let you make more kinds of assignments without incurring warnings, but still protect against inadvertent attempts to modify const values. C++ would still not allow assigning a `char **` to a `const char **`, but it would let you get away with assigning a `char **` to a `const char * const *`.)

Comment: And from the better-known C++ faq: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17

Answer (score 11):

Just since nobody has posted the *solution*, here:

```
char *s1 = 0;
const char *s2 = s1; // OK...
char *a[MAX]; // aka char **
const char * const*ps = a; // no error!
```

(http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17 for why)

Comment: It should be noted that it won't work for C, only C++.

Comment: The question isn't marked [tag:C]. Is there any other reason for the downvote?

Comment: Just use `const_cast` if you want to bypass const-correctness. This solution is overly complicated.

Answer (score 10):

The [C++11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) explains this in a note in section `4.4` which says:

> [ Note: if a program could assign a pointer of type T** to a pointer
>   of type const T** (that is, if line #1 below were allowed), a program
>   could inadvertently modify a const object (as it is done on line #2).
>   For example,
>
> ```
> int main() {
> const char c = 'c';
> char* pc;
> const char** pcc = &pc; // #1: not allowed
> *pcc = &c;
> *pc = 'C'; // #2: modifies a const object
> }
> ```
>
> —end note ]

An interesting related question is [Given int **p1 and const int **p2 is p1 == p2 well formed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29018809/1708801).

Note the [C++ FAQ](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion) also has an explanation for this but I like the explanation from the standard better.

The conforming text that goes with the note is as follows:

> A conversion can add cv-qualifiers at levels other than the first in
>   multi-level pointers, subject to the following rules:56
>
> > Two pointer types T1 and T2 are similar if there exists a type T and
> >     integer n > 0 such that:
> >
> > > T1 is cv1,0 pointer to cv1,1 pointer to · · · cv1,n−1 pointer to cv1,n
> > >       T
> >
> > and
> >
> > > T2 is cv2,0 pointer to cv2,1 pointer to · · · cv2,n−1 pointer to cv2,n T
> >
> > where each cvi,j is const, volatile, const volatile, or nothing. The
> >     n-tuple of cv-qualifiers after the first in a pointer type, e.g.,
> >     cv1,1, cv1,2, · · · , cv1,n in the pointer type T1, is called the
> >     cv-qualification signature of the pointer type. An expression of type
> >     T1 can be converted to type T2 if and only if the following conditions
> >     are satisfied:
> >
> > - the pointer types are similar.
> > - for every j > 0, if const is in cv1,j then const is in cv2,j , and similarly for volatile.
> > - if the cv1,j and cv2,j are different, then const is in every cv2,k for 0 < k < j.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After reading your answer for a couple of times I finally got it!

Comment: @AntonTugolukov looks like you question was merged w/ this current one

Answer (score 6):

There are two rules here to note:

- There are no implicit casts between `T*` and `U*` if T and U are different types.
- You can cast `T*` to `T const *` implicitly. ("pointer to T" can be cast to "pointer to const T"). In C++ if `T` is also pointer then this rule can be applied to it as well (chaining).

So for example:

`char**` means: **pointer to pointer to char**.

And `const char**` means: **pointer to pointer to const char**.

Since **pointer to char** and **pointer to const char** are different types that don't differ only in const-ness, so the cast is not allowed. The correct type to cast to should be **const pointer to char**.

So to remain const correct, you must add the const keyword starting from the rightmost asterisk.

So `char**` can be cast to `char * const *` and can be cast to `const char * const *` too.

This chaining is C++ only. In C this chaining doesn't work, so in that language you cannot cast more than one levels of pointers const correctly.