# c++ const convert

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, casting, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why isnt it legal to convert (pointer to pointer to non-const) to a (pointer to pointer to a const)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220916/why-isnt-it-legal-to-convert-pointer-to-pointer-to-non-const-to-a-pointer-to-p)

I have a function:

```
bool isCirclePolygonIntersection(const Point*, const int*, const Point*,
                                 const Point**, const int*);
```

and I'm trying to call it like this:

```
isCirclePolygonIntersection(p, &r, poly_coord, poly, &poly_size)
```

where `poly` defined like this:

```
Point** poly = new Point*[poly_size];
```

and there is a compiler error when I'm trying to compile it:

```
error C2664: 'isCirclePolygonIntersection' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'Point **' to 'const Point **'
1>          Conversion loses qualifiers
```

from what I've learned is that you cannot give `const` argument to function when a function expects a non `const` argument, but it's fine otherwise.
Does anyone knows what is the problem??
Thanks.

Comment: It will work if you declare the argument `const Point *const *`.  (Well, it will work in C++, not in C.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parashift has a great explanation on why this is prohibited:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17

Answer (score 4):

You're correct; you *can* implicitly convert a `T *` to a `const T *`.  However, you *cannot* implicitly convert a `T **` to a `const T **`.  See this from the C FAQ: http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html.

Answer (score 4):

An implicit conversion from `Point**` to `const Point**` would open a hole in the type system, hence there is no such conversion in C++.

For details, see [Why am I getting an error converting a `Foo**` → `Foo const**`?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17)

Changing `const Point**` to `const Point * const *` will fix your problem.

By the way, why the additional indirection? That is, why do you use an array of pointers? I would suggest a `std::vector<Point>` instead. Or is `Point` a polymorphic base class?