# In C++, for some type T, how can I obtain a "const T**" from a "T**"?

Tags: c++, pointers, types, constants, type-conversion

I have the following C++ code snippet:

```
class T { };

void f(const T**) { }

int main() {
    T *x = new T[5];
    f(&x);
}
```

When I try to compile, g++ reports `invalid conversion from 'T**' to 'const T**'`. I have done [some research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108957/c-const-convert) and I understand this error. The typical fix is to change the definition of `f(const T**)` to `f(const T* const*)` which immediately fixes the problem.

Unfortunately, in my case, `f` is a function in another library and **I cannot change the definition of f**. How can I pass the address of `x` to `f`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead you can pass the address of a pointer storing the same value as `x`.

```
int main() {
    T *x = new T[5];
    T const *y = x;
    f(&y);
}
```

When `f` returns you can copy the value back into `x`.

You can also cast the address. A write through `T const *` to an object of type `T *` is not an aliasing violation.

```
int main() {
    T *x = new T[5];
    f(const_cast<T const**>(&x));
}
```

The fact that this is valid is less obvious that simply passing a copy and then assigning back to `x` in my opinion, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! I'm glad there is a type-safe solution that doesn't involve const-cast.

Answer (score 2):

```
T const* x = new T[5];
f(&x);
```

or

```
T *x = new T[5];
f(&const_cast< T const*& >( x ) );
```

Comment: +1 for awesome const-cast one-liners. In the interest of readability, however, I think I'll avoid that. =P

Comment: I wasn't aware you can use `const_cast` to references in that way. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
class T { };

void f(const T**) { }

int main() {
  T *x = new T[5];
  const T* y = x; // <====
  f(&y); // use y
}
```

http://ideone.com/oWZQR