# The compiler states that there's no matching function for a call, even though there is one in the prototype

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a binary search tree class, but the compiler is throwing errors. The bstNode.h file is here:

```
template <class Item, class Key>
class bstNode
{
public:
    bstNode();
    bstNode(const Item& init_data, const Key& init_key, bstNode<Item, Key> *init_left, bstNode<Item, Key> *init_right);
    ~bstNode();
    bstNode<Item, Key>* tree_copy(const bstNode<Item, Key>*& root);
private:
    Item data;
    Key key;
    bstNode* left;
    bstNode* right;
};

    template <class Item, class Key>
    //line 83 in the original code is below
bstNode<Item, Key>* bstNode<Item, Key>::tree_copy(const bstNode<Item, Key>*& root)
{
    bstNode<Item, Key>* l_ptr;
    bstNode<Item, Key>* r_ptr;
    if (root == NULL) return NULL;
    l_ptr = tree_copy(root -> left());
    r_ptr = tree_copy(root -> right());
    return new bstNode<Item, Key> (root -> data(), l_ptr, r_ptr);
}
```

The .h file compiles fine with an empty main function, but when I try it with the following bit of code in bstNode.cxx, it crashes, giving an error. The code is:

```
    #include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "bstNode.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bstNode<int, size_t>* root_ptr = NULL;
    bstNode<int, size_t>* copy_root_ptr = root_ptr -> tree_copy(root_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

And the error is:

```
bstNode.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
bstNode.cxx:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘bstNode<int, long unsigned int>::tree_copy(bstNode<int, long unsigned int>*&)’
bstNode.h:83: note: candidates are: bstNode<Item, Key>* bstNode<Item, Key>::tree_copy(const bstNode<Item, Key>*&) [with Item = int, Key = long unsigned int]
```

The prototype is exactly the same as the function's implementation, sans the bstNode:: so I'm not sure what's going on. I'm using the g++ compiler. Any ideas? Much appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I cut down on the code to try and highlight the problem.

Comment: It would help you (and us) if you could isolate the problem. Please reduce your program to the smallest complete program that still demonstrates the error. http://sscce.org/.

Comment: See [Why isn't it legal to convert pointer-to-pointer-to-non-const to pointer-to-pointer-to-const](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220916/why-isnt-it-legal-to-convert-pointer-to-pointer-to-non-const-to-a-pointer-to). Valid for reference to the pointers as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler (as in most cases) is right in rejecting the code. The problem is that there is no conversion from `T*&` to `const T*&`, so the existing function cannot be used.

**Why is that conversion not present?**

The reason for that conversion not to be present is that it would break const-correctness. Consider this example:

```
const int k = 10;
void f( const int*& kp ) {
   kp = &k;                 // Fine, the pointer promises not to change the object
}
int main() {
   int *p; 
   f( p );                 // Does not compile, but assume it would
                           // after the call, p points to k
   *p = 20;                // Modifying a constant!!!!
                           //    p never promised not to change the pointee
}
```

Now, a possible solution, since you do not need to modify the pointer passed to the function is to add even more `const`s to the signature:

```
bstNode<Item, Key>* tree_copy(const bstNode<Item, Key>* const & root);
```

In doing so, you are blocking the code from changing the pointer, which is the problem in the example above. But, if you really think about it,

*Why do you pass a reference to a pointer in the first place?*

Pointers are cheap to copy, so passing them by `const&` does not make much sense, and since you do not need the function to change the pointer that you are passing, passing by value will be both correct *and* potentially more efficient.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed modify my teacher's definitions. And I can't pass a const T*& into the function without making the function itself const, which I cannot do, since I can't modify the definition. Any advice?

Answer (score 6):

The prototype isn't exactly the same, because there's a `const`ness difference. The declaration is

```
 bstNode<Item, Key>* tree_copy(const bstNode<Item, Key>*& root);
```

(reference to const pointer) whereas you've called it as

```
 bstNode<int, size_t>* root_ptr;
 tree_copy(root_ptr);
```

so it's getting a reference to *non-const* pointer. And while you can pass a `foo *` to something that takes a `const foo *`, you can't pass a `foo *` by reference to something that takes a `const foo * &`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that must be it. I think I'll just take the reference out. It's unnecessary, only there because the teacher wanted it. I was very confused when he gave us the assignment, because if it was const and couldn't be modified, then what was the point of passing it as reference? I guess the compiler agreed. :D

Comment: @vanchagreen: Note that in `const T * &` the pointer is *not* const, it is a mutable pointer to a `const T`. It might help if you rewrite the consts to the right: `const T*&` is equivalent to `T const *&`, and not to `T *const &` (*reference to a const pointer to a non-const T*)

Comment: vanchagreen, if either David's answer or mine has solved the problem -- which it sounds like they have -- then you should accept one of them. (I think David's answer is a bit better even though mine currently has more upvotes, but you can accept mine instead if you happen to prefer it :-).)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm new to stack overflow. :D

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan 
Unfortunately I'm not allowed modify my teacher's definitions. And I can't pass a const T*& into the function without making the function itself const, which I cannot do, since I can't modify the definition. Any advice?

Comment: As to the last question: you could declare `root_ptr` to be `const bstNode *` instead of just `bstNode *`. Or make another variable that's `const bstNode *`, assign `root_ptr` to it, and call `tree_copy` on that.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I'll go back and do that then, thanks. As for the question, if I were to make bstNode a const, wouldn't I have to make the function itself const?

Comment: `tree_copy` doesn't actually use the object it's being called on, so if you declare `root_ptr` non-const, make a const version of it, and call `root_ptr.tree_copy(const_root_ptr)`, I think that will work. It's ugly, but the real fault is in the weird way `tree_copy` is declared, and there's nothing you can do about that.