# Can't pass non-const T* to a function accepting reference to const T*

Tags: c++, reference, implicit-conversion, const-correctness, pointer-conversion

I am confused that why following code is not able to compile

```
int foo(const float* &a) {
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    float* a;
    foo(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler give error as:

> > error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const float*&' from expression of type 'float*'

When I try to pass without by reference in `foo`, it is compiling fine.

I think it should show same behavior whether I pass by reference or not.

Comment: It will work if you declare it as: `const float* a;`

Comment: Well you can make it `const float *a` in `main`, or `const float * const &a` in the function signature. I'm not sure what you want exactly.

Comment: I want to know reason for this behavior. Why is it not compiling when I pass by reference. I can not just simply change declaration as it would affect other calls where this variable is used.

Comment: Same problem as here https://stackoverflow.com/q/2220916/5740428, just with references instead of pointers

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Because it isn't type-safe.  Consider:

```
const float f = 2.0;
int foo(const float* &a) {
    a = &f;
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    float* a;
    foo(a);
    *a = 7.0;

    return 0;
}
```

Any non-`const` reference or pointer must necessarily be *invariant* in the pointed-to type, because a non-`const` pointer or reference supports reading (a covariant operation) and also writing (a contravariant operation).

`const` must be added from the greatest indirection level first.  This would work:

```
int foo(float* const &a) {
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    float* a;
    foo(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just want to emphasize: "must be added from the greatest indirection level _first_," because when `const` is added at a higher level it's also allowed at lower levels: `int foo(float const * const &a)`.

Comment: Could you please point a novice like me to something that talks about *covariant operation* or *greatest indirection level*?  Thanks..

Comment: This was killing me. Your example was great.