# a bad call with a const signature in C

Tags: c, warnings, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why isnt it legal to convert (pointer to pointer to non-const) to a (pointer to pointer to a const)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220916/why-isnt-it-legal-to-convert-pointer-to-pointer-to-non-const-to-a-pointer-to)

Why do I get a warning (gcc 42.2) with the following call of foo?

```
void foo(const char **str)
{
  (*str)++;  
}

(...)
char **str;
foo(str);
(...)
```

I understand why we cannot call a function that excepting a `char **` with a `const char **`, but the opposite seems ok to me, so why the following warning?

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'foo' from incompatible pointer type
```

Comment: which compilation tags are you using?

Comment: I think it is not legal though with such an incompatible assignment you can be subvert **const** in some situations without casting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is wrong.  There is no real room for arguing with the compiler here, since it's supported by the spec.  Here's an example which explains exactly why it is wrong:

```
void func(const char **p)
{
    *p = "abc";
}

void func2(void)
{
    char *a;
    func(&a);
    *a = 'x';
}
```

If the compiler didn't spit out an error, your program would probably crash because you'd be overwriting a string literal (which is often marked read-only in memory).

So you cannot implicitly cast `char **` to `const char **` because it would allow you to remove the `const` qualifier from any value — basically, it would allow you to ignore `const` at will without an explicit cast.

The main reason the compiler gives a warning instead of an error is because lots of old code does not use the `const` qualifier where it would if the code were written today.