# Given int **p1 and const int**p2 is p1 == p2 well formed?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

Given the following function:

```
void g(int **p1, const int**p2)
{
   if (p1 == p2) { }  
}
```

`clang`(*back to version 3.0*) produces this warning (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lCtOd2FagxDI9n2T)*):

```
warning: comparison of distinct pointer types ('int **' and 'const int **')
uses non-standard composite pointer type 'const int *const *' 
[-Wcompare-distinct-pointer-types]
  if (p1 == p2) { }
      ~~ ^ ~~
```

Using `-pedantic-errors` flags turns it into an error. Neither `gcc`(*back to 4.3.6*) nor `Visual Studio`(*2013*) produce a warning, according to the standard, is the comparison:

```
p1 == p2
```

well formed?

More generally, if two multi-level pointers differ in their *cv-qualifications* other than at the first level is comparison via the equality operator or relational operators well-formed?

Comment: very useful to know, upvoted. hope msvc and g++ follow suit in implementing c++14.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf gcc and VS already follow C++14 if they allow this code without a warning or error; clang needs fixing

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Thanks. Some binary switching in my mind there.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf added to my answer a clang commit from five years ago that indicates this was treated as an extension by clang, gcc and EDG and I presume also VS. Note at the meeting it was accepted at it indicated that this changed just codified existing practice.

Answer (score 24):

Before C++14 this case was ill-formed and the more general case with some exceptions was also ill-formed. This is covered in [defect report 1512: Pointer comparison vs qualification conversions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1512) , which says:

> According to 5.9 [expr.rel] paragraph 2, describing pointer
>   comparisons,
>
> > Pointer conversions (4.10 [conv.ptr]) and qualification conversions (4.4 [conv.qual]) are performed on pointer operands (or on
> >     a pointer operand and a null pointer constant, or on two null pointer
> >     constants, at least one of which is non-integral) to bring them to
> >     their composite pointer type.
>
> This would appear to make the following example ill-formed,
>
> ```
> bool foo(int** x, const int** y) {
>    return x < y;  // valid ?
> }
> ```
>
> because int** cannot be converted to const int**, according to the
>   rules of 4.4 [conv.qual] paragraph 4. This seems too strict for
>   pointer comparison, and current implementations accept the example.

The defect report points out although this was ill-formed, implementations accepted such comparisons. This [clang commit](http://llvm.org/klaus/clang/commit/b2cb1cbd727469e1567a6f2535895e6b64e12c35/) indicates it was treated as an extension and indicates both `gcc` and `EDG` also treats this as an extension, presumably this is also the case for Visual Studio.

This was resolved in the standard by [N3624: Core Issue 1512: Pointer comparison vs qualification conversions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3624.html), which says:

> This paper presents the modifications to the Working Draft necessary
>   to resolve core issues 583 and 1512. In particular, it makes
>
> [...]
>
> and
>
> ```
> void g(int **p1, const int**p2)
> {
>    if (p1 == p2) { ... }
> }
> ```
>
> well-formed.

Also note that in the [meeting it was accepted](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3622.pdf) it was noted that this just codified existing practice.

Amongst other changes to the standard, this paragraph was added to the end of section `5` *[expr]*, which includes the new term *cv-combined type*:

> The cv-combined type of two types T1 and T2 is a type T3 similar to T1
>   whose cv-qualification signature (4.4) is:
>
> - for every j > 0, cv3,j is the union of cv1,j and cv2,j ;
> - if the resulting cv3,j is different from cv1,j or cv2,j , then const is added to every cv3,k for 0 < k < j.
>
> [ Note: Given similar types T1
>   and T2, this construction ensures that both can be converted to T3.
>   —end note ] The composite pointer type of two operands p1 and p2
>   having types T1 and T2, respectively, where at least one is a pointer
>   or pointer to member type or std::nullptr_t, is:
>
> - if both p1 and p2 are null pointer constants, std::nullptr_t;
> - if either p1 or p2 is a null pointer constant, T2 or T1, respectively;
> - if T1 or T2 is “pointer to cv1 void” and the other type is “pointer to cv2 T”, “pointer to cv12 void”, where cv12 is the union of cv1 and
>     cv2 ;
> - if T1 is “pointer to cv1 C1” and T2 is “pointer to cv2 C2”, where C1 is reference-related to C2 or C2 is reference-related to C1 (8.5.3),
>     the cv-combined type of T1 and T2 or the cv-combined type of T2 and
>     T1, respectively;
> - if T1 is “pointer to member of C1 of type cv1 U1” and T2 is “pointer to member of C2 of type cv2 U2” where C1 is reference-related to C2 or
>     C2 is reference-related to C1 (8.5.3), the cv-combined type of T2 and
>     T1 or the cv-combined type of T1 and T2, respectively;
> - if T1 and T2 are similar multi-level mixed pointer and pointer to member types (4.4), the cv-combined type of T1 and T2;
> - otherwise, a program that necessitates the determination of a composite pointer type is ill-formed.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
>     typedef void *p;
>     typedef const int *q;
>     typedef int **pi;
>     typedef const int **pci;
> ```
>
> The composite pointer type of p and q is “pointer to const void”; the
>   composite pointer type of pi and pci is “pointer to const pointer to
>   const int”. —end example ]

Comment: Under what circumstances could an `int**` and a `const int**` actually be equal, without `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: @immibis the strict aliasing rule says that the compiler can assume `*x` does not alias `*y` (the same is not true for `**x` and `**y` obviously), so I suspect this test could be optimized to `false` (once it is permitted!)

Comment: @MattMcNabb No, it can't. Strict aliasing allows access through "a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object". `const int *` is *similar* to `int *`.

Comment: @immibis The trivial answer is "if both are null pointers". Anyway, converting between `int**` and `const int**` merely requires a `const_cast`, not a `reinterpret_cast`, and I suspect that it is valid to use the resulting pointer in all the usual and expected ways.