# c++: why can't we convert char ** to const char **

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I know that `const char * p` means we can't change the value which is pointed by `p` through `p`.

Now I'm writing a function which will take the parameters of the function `main`. Meaning that this function will take a `char **`. So I write this function like this:
`void func(const char **);`.
But when I pass the parameter of `main` to it, I get an error:

```
error C2664: 'void func(const char **)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'char **' to 'const char **'
```

I just want to initialize a `const` pointer with a `non-const` pointer. This should work. If we do the opposite thing, we should get some error. But now I don't know why I get this error.

Comment: You need to show us the code that generates the error!

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match the question body.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I just want to initialize a const pointer with a non-const pointer. This should be work.

That's not what you're trying to do, no.

You're trying to initialise a non-`const` pointer to pointer to `const char`, with a non-`const` pointer to pointer to `char`. That is never performed implicitly. *Why*? [It's well documented elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2220916/560648) because it's not completely intuitive to all but, in short, if converting `char**` to `const char**` were allowed, then `const`-correctness would be violated.

It's not the same as converting `char**` to `char** const`, which is what you think you're trying to do.

It's unfortunate that `main`'s arguments do not already have `const` strewn about them. Sorry. Fortunately, you can work around it with a `const_cast`:

```
void foo(const char** argv) {}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   foo(const_cast<const char**>(argv));
}
```

This is one of those situations in which using `const_cast` to hack around pre-existing silliness, contrary to the wishes of the type system, is actually okay.