# const pointer as std::bind parameter

Tags: c++, stdbind

The following code

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct TestStruct {
  int c;
};

int f(int a, int b, const TestStruct **t) { return a + b + (*t)->c; }

void main() {

  TestStruct *t;
  bind(&f, 1, 2, &t)();
}
```

reports this error

```
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'
note: With the following template arguments:
note: '_Callable=int (__cdecl *&)(int,int,const TestStruct **)'
note: '_Types={int &, int &, TestStruct **&}'
```

It seems that the problem is the constness of the `const TestStruct**` param. However, there's no problem neither with `const TestStruct *` nor with `TestStruct**`. Why ?

Comment: Did you intend to write `TestStruct** const`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No. I've simplified, the `f` function is an external `C` function which i want to bind to, and its signature is like that.

Comment: You cannot. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2220916/560648

Comment: By the way: `main` returns `int`, not `void`.

Comment: [Easy workaround here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/479116cbfd4744f9)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem does not come from bind itself, but from the simple fact that casting `T**` to `T const**` is illegal.

see http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html for an explanation as to why.