# Initializing pointer to pointer to const float etc. using new operator

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider the following declarations :

```
const float** b;
const float* const* c;
float* const* d;
```

First off all I want to make sure that :

- `b` is a `pointer` to `pointer` to `const float`.
- `c` is a `pointer` to `const pointer` to `const float`.
- `d` is a `pointer` to a `const pointer` to `float`.

Now my question is how can I initialize each pointer using new `operator`?

Comment: do you actually want to create a new float, create an array of floats, create an array of arrays of floats, or point to existing of any of the above?

Comment: Just a new float to not to make things complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const float** b = new const float*();
const float* const* c = new const float*(nullptr);
float* const* d = new float*(nullptr);
```

the type with one less indirection and set values if they point on const

Comment: wow. this is putting a loaded handgun into the hands of a child!

Comment: @RichardHodges he asked for it

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I noticed that the compiler gives no error when I omit `const` keyword on the right hand side in some cases. For instance:

`const float* const* b = new const float*`

`const float* const* b = new float*`

`const float* const* histRange=new float*((float*)(new float(45)))`

`const float* const* histRange=new const float*((float*)(new float(45)))`

all of them work. (At least they are compiled without an error). But this gives error:

`const float** b = new float*`

I really don't understand when I have to use `const` and when I don't have to.

Comment: @ademsonmez `const float**` is a pointer on pointer on constant float so you need to new a pointer on constant float

Comment: @Tyker How about `const float* const* histRange=new float*(nullptr)` it is also `pointer to const pointer to const float` but you can initialize it without using `const`

Comment: @ademsonmez this comes from implict convertions, in `const float* const* histRange=new float*(nullptr)` you are converting a `float**` to `const float * const *` wich is allowed but converting from from `float**` to `const float**` isn't, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220916/why-isnt-it-legal-to-convert-pointer-to-pointer-to-non-const-to-a-pointer-to for more detail