# Avoid warning: expected ‘const struct aiocb * const*’ but argument is of type ‘struct aiocb **’

Tags: c, linux, constants, posix

```
archives.c: In function ‘fd_writeback_wait’:
archives.c:121:21: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘aio_suspend’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     r = aio_suspend(&cb, 1, NULL);
                     ^~~
In file included from ../lib/dpkg/fsys.h:28,
                 from ../lib/dpkg/triglib.h:28,
                 from archives.c:57:
/usr/include/aio.h:168:51: note: expected ‘const struct aiocb * const*’ but argument is of type ‘struct aiocb **’
 extern int aio_suspend (const struct aiocb *const __list[], int __nent,
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

Explanations:

- [Why isn't it legal to convert "pointer to pointer to non-const" to a "pointer to pointer to const"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220916/why-isnt-it-legal-to-convert-pointer-to-pointer-to-non-const-to-a-pointer-to)
- ... or look at the Related questions list on the right hand side of the screen, and take your pick :-).

I think there is no way to avoid this warning, without writing a dangerous type cast to change the const qualifiers, or suppressing the whole category of warnings.

Apparently C++ does better here.  It also has `const_cast` for clearer casting, which makes sure that you are *only* changing const qualifiers.

In other words, POSIX defining [aio_suspend()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/aio_suspend.html) to use `const` like this is arguably rather dangerous.

Have I interpreted this correctly?

If I am wrong, then how can I avoid this warning, but still have the compiler check that I am only casting `const` qualifiers, and not casting to a completely incompatible type?

---

I suspect if there are methods, they would not be ones that I would want to use in practice, but I am curious.

The current code I am working on does not explicitly document a required compiler version.

I would be interested in techniques that work in standard C versions.  I would be interested to hear about GCC extensions.  Comments about whether it is recommended or dis-recommended to define function parameters like this are also welcome.

Readers are reminded that C and C++ are different, and *not* 100% compatible languages.  I acknowledge that switching code bases to C++ could probably provide a solution, but I do not think that solution would be very useful to me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to call the function with appropriate `const`ness:

```
struct aiocb cb;
const struct aiocb * cblist[1] = { &cb };
aio_suspend(cblist, 1, NULL);
```

And alternatively:

```
struct aiocb cb;
const struct aiocb * cbptr = &cb;
aio_suspend(&cbptr, 1, NULL);
```

Note, the above answer was proposed because you used this syntax:

```
r = aio_suspend(&cb, 1, NULL);
```

Passing in the address of `cb` to something that expects a pointer to pointer means `cb` was a pointer, so this call only makes sense for a single element array.

Suppose your warning came about because you actually had this:

```
struct aiocb *cbv[256];
r = aio_suspend(cbv, 256, NULL);
```

It is easy to remove the warning. Use `(void *)`.

```
r = aio_suspend((void *)cbv, 256, NULL);
```

However, it would be better to define the vector to be using pointers to `const` in the first place.

```
const struct aiocb *cbv[256];
r = aio_suspend(cbv, 256, NULL);
```

If each callback instance is indeed modifiable in reality (eg, was allocated by `malloc`), then just cast away const before modifying.

```
struct aiocb *cb = (struct aiocb *)cbv[i];
/* ... modify cb ... */
```

Comment: Point! And for the call site this exact warning is about, that would be fine. But I also have a call site where the array has up to 256 entries, and is modified and re-used.  Even if it's possible to copy the entire array into a const local variable, and even if the optimizer knows how to elide the copy, I suspect that would not be very idiomatic C code.

Comment: @sourcejedi: You did not actually present such a use case. I have expanded my answer nevertheless.

Comment: Absolutely agreed, and I apologize :-). Nitpick: both `cb` and `&cb` work if `cb` is declared as `struct aiocb *cb[1]` - arrays are weird like that.  You would be right if you guessed that I did not write my code like that though :-).

Comment: They might have the same address, but they have different types. https://tio.run/##ZYzBCsIwEETv@YoBQVqxUs8Vf0SkpNtYA3Fbks1J@uvG1ZPgMKd5j6FmIiobzxTy6HCyfj7cz8Z4FjysZ1Q1ngUamjkJksRMAtVowA40hMvx2pmPoFufclocj5Xue7Ta@p9tf@D3OTrJkdF2Zi0vugU7pdKEKG8

Comment: FWIW, adding a few `const` qualifiers in the right place has now avoided both the compiler warning, and the need for any type casts to add/remove consts.  It seems the POSIX `aio_suspend()` is entirely usable after all :-).  Thanks.