# Error Can not convert char** to const char**

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++, const-correctness

I have following code:-

```
static char* ListOfStr[] = { "str1", "str2", "str3" };
void Foo(const char** listOfStr)
{
// do something
}
```

When I call `Foo` like;

```
Foo(ListOfStr);
```

I get Error Can not convert char** to const char** (C2664 - vc++)

I know how to solve the problem using casting or other way around like defining const array at first place.

But isn't it safe to use char** as const char** than why it gives error ?
I supposed there should be auto convertion like `std::string` to `const std::string` when passing to function. Only the reverse of this `cont char**` to `char**` must give the Error without cast.

Comment: This is because in modern C++ a `"literal string"` is a `const char *` and not a `char *`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The error message seems to indicate *the opposite* problem.

Comment: If you don't get an error on the first line, then this is C. Why have you tagged the question with C++?

Comment: @S.M. Probably every compiler out there permits this legacy initialization with some option; VC++ will need "conformance mode off". This is not the issue here. The issue is that with double pointers certain conversions *towards const* are prohibited.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica yes, you are right I missed it, I blame Sam ;)

Comment: @anastaciu It is a very red herring, granted ;-)

Comment: @Peter OP did not indicate this, thus we can assume the default compiler settings used.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/2220916/6865932

Comment: You can declare `Foo` as `Foo(const char* const* listOfStr)`, which avoids the trap in the duplicate, since the passed pointer is no longer mutable so you can't use it to swap in a const for a non-const.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks your way of declaring the `Foo` Also explains why it is forbidden to convert `char**` to `const char**`. I get my answer.

Comment: @RaymondChen Nitpick: The "passed pointer", listOfStr, is still not const in `const char* const* listOfStr`; that would only be `const char* const* const listOfStr`! (The second const makes the intermediate pointer level const.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is covered in the C++ FAQ, thanks to Steve Summit: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion

I have looked at it for 10 minutes and still don't fully understand it, but the problem is apparently that you could create non-const aliases and thus modify  an originally const object if this were allowed.

Comment: At the end, if every step was legal, q would point to p and p would point to x, with q and x being const, but not p, which is a problem. q was basically used in order to make p point to x within `*q = &x; ` (with *q being p at that moment). Thus, one step must be forbidden. All lines except the one in the middle are something done commonly. I think if I hadn't read your link, I'd never guessed that this harmless looking line is actually dangerous in a hundred years.

Comment: @Aziuth q is not const either... it points to pointers to const.