# Temporary object creation for reference parameter and optimization changes

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, clang++, const-correctness, reference-binding

I have the following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void foo(const int* const &i_p) {
    std::cout << &i_p << std::endl;
}

int main () {

    int i = 10;
    int* i_p = &i;
    std::cout << &i_p << std::endl;
    foo(i_p);
}
```

On `x86-64 clang 9.0.0` the output is

```
Program returned: 0
0x7ffc43de63f8
0x7ffc43de6400
```

while on `x86-64 clang 10.0.0` [Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/oTd89nKxe) the output becomes

```
Program returned: 0
0x7ffc9da01ef0
0x7ffc9da01ef0
```

What optimization is at play here that gives the same address? I believe a temporary object should materialize since we cannot bind low-level `const` pointer to low-level `non-const`.

Comment: Given that `foo()` cannot actually modify its parameter, `clang` is smart enough to hijack `main()`'s stack frame and recycle it in `foo()`? All references themselves are, by definition `const`, for all practical matters. It should be interesting if the same optimization works for a non-reference, but a `const` parameter.

Comment: With a few additional minutes' worth of thought, this cannot be a valid optimization in some cases. Here, the compiler can theoretically prove, thanks to LTO, that there are no other execution threads. But in a code that uses multiple execution threads, another execution thread can modify  `i_p` anytime, resulting in this optimization being able to observe it, in `foo()`. Fail.

Comment: Several objects of different types might have same address. In particular, [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) has been added in C++20 so associated optimization code might be used more widely?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this with multiple environments and optimizations and I cannot replicate the 8 byte shift you are seeing with clang 9.0.0.  Does this consistently happen?  I wonder if it is a byte boundary issue considering the shift is less than the size of an int.  Also does this happen if you pack the entire int? ex. int I = 0xffffffff;

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That optimization would not be permitted in any situation. The lifetime of `i_p` in `main` ends only after the function call. So `i_p` in `main` and a temporary object bound to the function parameter (if there was one) are not allowed to have the same address, because their lifetimes overlap.

Comment: @Jarod42 Two (non-bitfield) objects that have overlapping lifetime may only have the same address if one is nested within the other or one is a subobject of zero size (+ further restrictions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What optimization is at play here that gives the same address? I believe a temporary object should materialize since we cannot bind low-level `const` pointer to low-level non-`const`.

There is no trick:

- it is valid to convert an `int*` to `const int*`, and
- it is valid to convert an `int**` to a `const int * const *`, however
- it is **not** valid to convert `int**` to `const int**` (but that case isn't relevant here).

See [Why isn't it legal to convert "pointer to pointer to non-const" to a "pointer to pointer to const"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2220916/5740428).

#### Current wording

You only have a single `i_p` pointer, and naturally, both `&i_p` in `main` and `&i_p` in `foo` should yield the same address.
`foo` accepts a reference to a pointer, so it should refer to that in `main`.

`const int * const` is [reference-compatible](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#def:reference-compatible) with `int *` because a a pointer to `int*`, i.e. `int**` could be converted to `const int * const*` via a [qualification conversion](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual).
Due to this, a reference to `const int * const` can bind to `int*`.

There is nothing which would necessitate the creation of a second object, at least not in the current draft.
`const int&` can bind to `int` without creating a separate object, and the same principle applies to your case.

#### Historical defects explaining your observed behavior

However, it didn't always use to be like that, and qualification conversions haven't always been considered during reference binding.
[CWG2018. Qualification conversion vs reference binding](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2018) points out that qualification conversions aren't considered and temporary objects are created, such as in this example:

> ```cpp
> const int &r1 = make<int&>();           // ok, binds directly
> const int *const &r2 = make<int*&>();   // weird, binds to a temporary
> const int *&r3 = make<int*&>();         // error
>
> const int &&x1 = make<int&&>();         // ok, binds directly
> const int *const &&x2 = make<int*&&>(); // weird, binds to a temporary
> const int *&&x3 = make<int*&&>();       // weird, binds to a temporary
> ```

*Note: there is still some compiler divergence; GCC considers `x3` to be ill-formed, and clang performs temporary materialization.*

The example `r2` is exactly your case.
If the `const int* const &i_p` isn't simply binding to the `i_p` in `main` but creates a brand new temporary pointer when `foo` is called, then it would be a separate object. Note that `const&` can bind to temporary objects thanks to temporary materialization.
If there is a separate temporary object which `i_p` in `foo` binds to, then it would also need to have a separate address from that in `main`.

This behavior is a defect though, fixed by [CWG2352: Similar types and reference binding](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2352.html).
The new wording was implemented in GCC 7 and clang 10, which is why you no longer see two separate pointers being created.