# Can you bind a const T*&& to an xvalue of type T*?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, temporary-objects, const-correctness, reference-binding

Consider the following code: (https://godbolt.org/z/8W699x6q6)

```cpp
int* p;
const int*&& r = static_cast<int*&&>(p);
```

*Note: `const int*&&` is an rvalue reference to a pointer to `const int`.*

Clang compiles this, and `r` binds to a temporary object:

```cpp
p: .quad   0
r: .quad   _ZGR1r_ // r is a reference to a temporary object, otherwise this would be p
```

GCC rejects this code:

```cpp
<source>:2:18: error: binding reference of type 'const int*&&' to 'int*' discards qualifiers
    2 | const int *&&r = static_cast<int*&&>(p);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Personally, I think GCC correctly implements the changes of [CWG 2352](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2352.html) to [[dcl.init.ref] p4](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#4) but I'm not confident that I'm interpreting things right.
Which compiler is correct here?

---

*Note: the example in this question is inspired by the last line of code mentioned in [CWG 2018](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2018.html).*

*Note: if it was allowed to bind `const int*&&` to `int*&&`, [this would present a const-correctness footgun](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2220916/5740428). It's the same issue as converting `int**` to `const int**`. Personally, I think it's unlikely that the committee wants this reference binding to be allowed, however, maybe the wording still allows for it despite the defect report.*

Comment: Just to clarify, `T const*` is a different type from `T*`. Specifically, it's not a `T* const`, you are specifically asking about a non-const pointer to a const T - right? You *can* of course initialize a temporary `T const*` from a `T*` xvalue, that is a valid conversion.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about the binding of an rvalue ref to to pointer to const T.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the definitions given in [[dcl.init.ref]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#4),

- "pointer to `const int`" is not reference-compatible with "pointer to `int`", because `int**` is not convertible to `const int**`.
- "pointer to `const int`" is reference-related to "pointer to `int`" because these two types are similar.

Reference-compatibility governs when a direct binding is possible. Such a direct binding must respect const-correctness: if an `int*` object `p` could be referred to via a reference `r` to non-const `const int*`, then the value of a `const int*` could be written through `r`, thus copying its value into `p`. Thus, this direct binding is not allowed. However, if the referenced type is itself const (that is, the referenced type is `const int* const`) then it is reference-compatible with `int*` under [[conv.qual]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#3). (Bullet 3.3 requires the extra `const`.)

If the necessary reference-compatible relationship existed, this reference binding would be governed by [[dcl.init.ref]/5.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.3). In this case, because the referenced type is not reference-compatible with the initializer's type, we instead fall through to [[dcl.init.ref]/5.4.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.4.2), which requires a temporary object of type `const int*` to be created; the reference binds to that object and not the initializer.

I agree with the OP that this outcome seems unintended. CWG2018 referred to the following indirect reference bindings as "weird":

- reference to `const int* const` binding to `int*`
- reference to `const int*` binding to `int*`

The former was made a direct reference binding by CWG2352. The latter cannot be a direct binding because such a direct binding would violate const correctness, so it should be ill-formed.

A further rationale for making this reference binding ill-formed is analogy with:

```
const int x = 0;
int&& r = std::move(x);
```

This does not make a copy of `x` and bind the reference to the temporary; it is ill-formed. The reason why the creation of a temporary isn't permitted in this case is that the referenced type is "too close" to the initializer's type: namely, the two types are reference-related. The reference-relatedness causes p5.4.3 to kick in:

> *cv1* shall be the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv2*; [...]

CWG2352 extended reference-relatedness to cases like that given by the OP. It seems likely that an oversight in the drafting led to the current inconsistency.

Newly created [CWG2801](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2801.html) proposes wording to rectify the issue, making the OP's code ill-formed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, GCC is correct here. The wording in [[dcl.init.ref]#4](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#4) and [[dcl.init.ref]#5.3.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.3.1) only apply if T1 and T2 have a similar [qualification decomposition](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#1), in that a prvalue pointer to of T1 can be converted to a pointer to T2.

Here their respective sequences for the attempted conversions are `* pcv1, * U, [int]` and `* pcv1, * const U, [int]`. If the `const` was instead bound to the pointer (aka *cv0*, which [isn't considered](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#3.1) when comparing cv signatures), the types *would* be compatible, as they would have otherwise similar sequences. But instead the decomposition Tj doesn't match T2, and since the requirement for [prvalue conversion](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv#qual-3) is that Tj is the same as T2, they are not similar. This means the conversion sequence would be ill-formed, and therefore the binding is ill-formed.

The reason it is ill-formed is that with lvalue references, by binding a `T*` to a `const T*&`, you would be able to modify a `const` object.