# Can't add bottom-level const

Tags: c++

I have a situation in my code with a function of this sort:

```
void F1(const int** ppi);

void F2()
{
    int* pi = nullptr;
    F1(&pi); // error: cannot convert from 'int **' to 'const int **'
             // Conversion loses qualifiers
}
```

I remember reading an explanation many years ago about why this isn't allowed, but I can't remember. Something about such a conversion eventually allowing you to modify the pointed-to int.

To further confuse me, I can fix it by adding another const at the second level and I don't know why:

```
void F1(const int* const* ppi);
```

Comment: It is explained in many introductory books on C++, and also in many questions and answers on this very site of web, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220916/why-isnt-it-legal-to-convert-pointer-to-pointer-to-non-const-to-a-pointer-to)

Comment: Last one is a **Pointer to const pointer to const int**.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Bjarne Stroustrup's flagship book doesn't seem to cover it, at least in the section about pointers and const. Could have done without the snark, but thanks anyway.

Comment: The answer is also in the C++ FAQ: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion

Comment: Hm, I was sure I've learned this from Stroustrup, but now I can't find it anywhere in his books. Must have been something else, probably "C++ Gotchas". Also Bjarne's FAQ contains an [entry](https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#conversion), which at the first glance looks completely unrelated to `const int**`, but conceptually it's about the same thing.