# Can I have a C++ method that accepts both const-ref and non-const-ref pointers?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, reference, constants

I have a few helper methods that accept a pointer by reference, advancing it forward if certain conditions are met. Here's an example:

```cpp
char32_t readCodePoint(const char8_t *&current, const char8_t *end) {
  assert((current < end) && u8"At least one byte of input must be available");

  char8_t leadCharacter = *current;
  if(leadCharacter < 128) {
    ++current;
    return static_cast<char32_t>(leadCharacter);
  } else if((leadCharacter & 0xE0) == 0xC0) {
    // ...code for 2, 3 and 4 byte code points omitted...
    // (all increment 'current' accordingly and respect 'end')
  }

  // Sequence invalid or truncated
  return char32_t(-1);
}
```

Now I can use that method on `const char8_t *` pointers, but it forces the pointer to be `const`. The following would result in a compile error:

```cpp
void collapseDuplicateWhitespace(std::u8string &utf8String) {
  char8_t *current = utf8String.data();
  char8_t *end = current + utf8String.length();

  while(current < end) {
    // ERROR: 'current' is a 'char8_t *' not a 'const char8_t *'
    char32_t codePoint = readCodePoint(current, end);
    // ... other logic ommitted ...
  }

  // ... resize string to new, shorter length ...
}
```

Obviously, the result of a `const_cast` can't be passed as reference directly either, so it leads some really unsightly code on the caller side that might even introduce aliasing issues in release builds.

Is there an elegant (and preferably readable) way in which I could alter this method to work with both `const char8_t *&` and `char8_t *&` as the type of `current`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm at a loss here. It is always possible to call `f(const *T)` with a `T*` argument, isn't it? The other way around is problematic.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica yes, but that's not OP's case. Notice that it's `const char8_t*&`, i.e. an lvalue reference to a pointer to `const char8_t`. It is not possible to call this function if adding `const` is needed. This would lead to the [infamous const-correctness bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2220916/5740428).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica If it was just a mere pointer (i.e. calling a `const X *` method with `X *`) then yes, but rather than `const X *`, I have `const X *&` (I'm passing the pointer by reference)

Comment: @Cygon Oh, thanks, I missed that.

Comment: I cannot find the need of `const char8_t *&` in `readCodePoint()`. Could you elaborate on why reference is required?

Comment: @Louis Go: `readCodePoint()` advances the pointer to the next code point. See `++current` in the first `if` statement (and in the omitted parts, as hinted at by the comment, it would advance the pointer by 2, 3 or 4 bytes according to number of UTF-8 characters required to represent the code point).

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution A

The low-hanging fruit solution is a template:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
concept possibly_const = std::same_as<T, const U> || std::same_as<T, U>;  

char32_t readCodePoint(possibly_const<char8_t> auto *&current, const char8_t *end) {
    // ...
}
```

#### Solution B

Another solution is to rewrite your code to work with indices intead of pointers, which eliminates the question of constness here:

```cpp
char32_t readCodePoint(std::span<const char8_t> data, std::ptrdiff_t &index) {
    // ...
}
```

#### Solution C

Yet another solution is to eliminate the statefulness in your code completey.
Simply return the character you've read and the amount you've read:

```cpp
struct ReadCodePointResult {
    unsigned byte_size;
    char32_t code_point;

    // for convenience:
    explicit operator bool() const {
        return byte_size != 0;
    }
};

ReadCodePointResult readCodePoint(const char8_t *current, const char8_t *end) {
    // ...
}
```

You can then use it like

```cpp
if (auto result = readCodePoint(/* ... */)) {
    // do something with result.code_point ...
    // advance by result.byte_size ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might add overload, and reuse implementation:

```
char32_t readCodePoint(char8_t *&current, const char8_t *end) {
    const char8_t *const_current = current;
    const auto res = readCodePoint(const_current, end);
    current = const_cast<char8_t *>(const_current);
    return res;
}
```

Assuming no exceptions, else it would be:

```
char32_t readCodePoint(char8_t *&current, const char8_t *end) {
    const char8_t *const_current = current;
    try {
        const auto res = readCodePoint(const_current, end);
        current = const_cast<char8_t *>(const_current);
        return res;
    } catch (...) {
        current = const_cast<char8_t *>(const_current);
        throw;
    }
}
```