mutability combinations for double pointer function parameter
I want to know how to modify the data that a pointer points to without modifying the original pointer (single pointer) by passing it as a double pointer argument to a function. These are the different combinations that I came up with
#include <iostream>

// pointer modification disabled, data modification disabled
void foo1(const int* const* dp) {
    std::cout << "foo1\n"; 
    std::cout << **dp << std::endl;
    int i = 4;
    int* p = &i;
    // *dp = p; // error
    // **dp = i; // error
    dp = &p;
}

// pointer modification enabled, data modification enabled
void foo2(int** dp) {
    std::cout << "foo2\n";
    std::cout << **dp << std::endl;
    **dp = 12;
    // *dp = nullptr;
}

// pointer modification disabled, data modification enabled
void foo3(int* const* dp) {
    std::cout << "foo3\n";
    std::cout << **dp << std::endl;
    // *dp = nullptr; // error
    **dp = 45;
}

// pointer modification enabled, data modification disabled
void foo4(const int** dp) {
    std::cout << "foo4\n";
    std::cout << **dp << std::endl;
    // **dp = 5; // error
    *dp = nullptr;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i = 3;
    int* p = &i;

    foo1(&p);

    foo2(&p);

    foo3(&p);

    foo4(&p); // doesn't compile
}

But I'm getting an error:
<source>:53:10: error: invalid conversion from 'int**' to 'const int**' [-fpermissive]
   53 |     foo4(&p);
      |          ^~
      |          |
      |          int**
<source>:36:23: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void foo4(const int**)'
   36 | void foo4(const int** dp) {
      |


What's your question?

foo4 does not work because it might end up violating const correctness down the line - see comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 11.10 and Double pointer const-correctness warnings in C for an example.

The error is legit.  You can't convert from int** to int const**.  Add this to main: int const* pc = &i;, and call foo4(&pc);.

@Turtlefight Is it possible to achieve the functionality of foo4 using double pointer?

But in C++, consider references for what you are trying to do:  void foo4(int const*& p) { std::cout << "foo4\n" << *p << "\n"; p = nullptr; }.  Much more idiomatic C++.

The problem is that "data modification" isn't fully disabled in case 4. See example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29240053/17398063

if you still think you need to use double pointers in "C++" then someone has been teaching you "C". Just stop doing that

The phase does not match the code provided, if you want to modify the pointed data without modifiying the pointer, you simply have to give the pointer value! If for some reason you want a double pointer (very bad idea in C++), you need  the foo3(int*const*addr_of_ptr).

"modify the data that a pointer points to without modifying the original pointer" - then there is no reason to pass the original pointer by pointer in the first place. Passing it by value avoids the problem completely.

@RemyLebeau I know passing it as a single pointer suffices, but just want to learn how to achieve the same using double pointer
